# issues When curl_easy_perform run in thread return code 7

Tags: libcurl

When curl_easy_perform run in thread return code 7 but not in main thread.
kernel 2.36.2  uClibc-0.9.33  libpthread.so-0.9.33.2

curl_east_perform work well in the below code:

```
int main(void)  {
CURL * curl = curl_easy_inint;
curl_easy_setopt();
curl_east_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup;
return 0;
}
```

curl_east_perform will always return 7 in the below code:

```
int main(void) {
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
pthread_create(pid, NULL, curl_run_process, NULL);
return 0;
}
void *curl_run_process(void *arg) {
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init;
curl_easy_setopt();
curl_east_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup;

}
```

Comment: I build this example "curl-7.47.1/docs/examples/multithread.c", and run in my board mt7628. and get the same issue.